# ダブルクォートと[鉤括弧]{かぎ・かっ・こ}の使い分けは？

Tags: punctuation

日本語の文章では、引用符として、ダブルクォート（””）も鉤括弧（「」）も両方使用されているのを見たことがあります。もちろん、他の引用符も見たことがありますが、それはさておきます。

ダブルクォートは英文に引用符をつける時に使われているような気がしますが、この使い分けは正式に認められていますか？公文書などではダブルクォートも鉤括弧も使えますか？

Comment: I feel like we should be more welcoming of questions and answers written in Japanese, so I wrote this one! Please do not hesitate to correct any mistakes I made.

Comment: 質問者が他でもなくJDさんですので、敢えて母語話者レベルで指摘させていただくなら、最初の一文は問題ありと言わざるを得ません。「引用符をつける時に」に続く語句として、「〜〜を見たことがあります」というのは不自然です。理由は、引用符をつけたのは他者であり、それを『後になって、活字として』見たことがあるのがJDさんご本人だからです。『誰かが引用符をつけている瞬間を目撃した』わけではないのです。従って、「～～をつける時に、XもYも両方使用されているようです」とするか、または、「見たことがあります」を残したいのであれば、「引用符として、XもYも両方使用されているのを見たことがあります」とすることもできます。第二文以降はお世辞抜きで自然な日本語になっていると思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「正式な」というのが、「義務教育の国語の授業で学ぶ」という意味であれば、Noです。中学校までに「日本語の文章を書く時の正式なダブルクォートの使い方」というものを学ぶことはないはずです。

また、ネットで参照できる [公用文の書き方の規程](http://www012.upp.so-net.ne.jp/KASHIWADANI/kouyoubunnokakikata.pdf) や [翻訳家向けのスタイルガイド](http://www.jtf.jp/jp/style_guide/styleguide_top.html) でも、日本語文章中でのダブルクォートの使い方について、全く、または、ほとんど載っていません。

例外的に、**科学技術文書**のガイドライン内で、ダブルクォートについて言及している文章がいくつか見つかりました。もちろんこれは、一般的な日本語文章を記述するためのものではありません。

> 引用符号“  ”は，語句を引用する場合，又は文字，記号，用語などを特に明らかにする必要がある場合に用いる。 なお，**かぎ括弧“ 「  」 ”は，用いない**。 ([JIS Z 8301：規格票の様式及び作成方法](http://kikakurui.com/z8/Z8301-2011-01.html))
>
> ---
>
> Q10. 横書きの文書ではかぎ括弧（「　」）に代えてダブル・クォーテーション・マーク（二重引用符）（“　”）を使うのですか。
> 【回答】（略）SIST全体では不統一で，**かぎ括弧と二重引用符を使い分けているわけではありませんが，両方使われています**。横書きでも縦書きと同じくかぎ括弧を利用する文書は多く見うけます。このように，現状はさまざまであり，作成する文書で統一を図る際にいずれかに決めればよいと考えます。このＱ＆Ａ文書では日本語にはかぎ括弧，英語には二重引用符を利用して，使い分けてみました。 ([科学技術情報流通技術基準 Q&A](http://sti.jst.go.jp/sist/qa/answer.html#q10))

その他にも、業界ごとに自分が知らない細かいルールがあるかもしれませんが、少なくとも「一般に広く認知されている統一的な基準」は、存在しないはずです。プロとして文章の仕事をする場合は、業界や会社の基準を調べ、それに従う必要があります。明確な基準がない場合、特にフォーマルな文書では、ダブルクォートは避けるのが無難だと思います。

もちろん、普段はあまり気にしなくていいです。

Answer (score 2):

[ウィキペディア](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BC%95%E7%94%A8%E7%AC%A6)によると、ダブルクォートの使用は日本語における用法では変則的ですが、NHKテレビのニュース字幕ではよく用いられています：

> **日本語における用法**
>
> 引用符について、日本語において一般に行われている用法または特徴的な用例を挙げる。
>
> - 引用した文章は、鉤括弧（「 」）で囲む。
> - 引用文の中にさらに語句を引用する場合、引用中の引用は二重鉤括弧（『 』）で囲む。
> - 引用した文章に鉤括弧が用いられている場合、鉤括弧は二重鉤括弧（『 』）に置き換える。
> - 引用文中に補足的説明を加える場合は、説明している部分を亀甲括弧（〔 〕）ないし大括弧（［ ］）で囲む。
> - 引用文の一部を強調する場合は、該当部分に傍点・傍線・下線・太字化などを施し、引用文の最後に丸括弧（（ ））を用いて引用者が強調した旨を記す。
> - 引用文の前略・中略をなす場合は、三点リーダー（…）ないし大括弧と三点リーダー（［…］）を用いる。
> - NHKテレビのニュース字幕では、変則的なダブルクォート（“ „）を用いている。

ところが、そのウィキペディアの記事自体は皮肉なことに何の情報源も引用していないから、どこまでこの情報を信頼できるか分かりません。