# quotation marks「」vs ””

Tags: symbols

In japanese writing, the ubiquitous 「」is used to mark speech. I have seen "" being used instead of 「」especially on messaging apps. Question is, what's the difference? For the record, I have only seen "" being used in messaging apps

Comment: Duplicate but the Q&A is in Japanese: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19004/ダブルクォートと鉤括弧かぎ-かっ-この使い分けは

Comment: There is no such a rule as "use only double-quotes in message apps", so you may be seeing some technical problem specific to your app.

Comment: @naruto I didn't mean to say that double quotes can only be used in messaging apps. What I really meant was, I have seen it in messaging apps only so far and not in books, etc

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Sounds to me like there are really no fixed rules and "" really just marks as phrase that one wants to emphasize

Comment: The English quotes may easily get confused with the voice symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary function of quotes is to enclose what someone said or thought, usually along with a quotative-と. For this basic purpose, the "proper" Japanese quotation marks (`「」`) are normally chosen, but other symbols are sometimes used in informal situations.

To highlight important or unfamiliar words, various symbols including `「」`, `“ ”`, `【】`, [傍点](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15270/5010) and so on are used, according to the writer's preference or the rule of a publisher. (Japanese does not have italics.) Perhaps `「」` is the most traditional, but `“ ”` is equally common. In general, many Japanese people do not make a strict distinction in the use of these symbols (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29341/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21274/5010)) to highlight words, so you don't have to worry too much.